# Trouble conceptualising Class use in a tracking project

Tags: c++, class, oop, opencv, tracking

I'm really having some trouble conceptualising my problem using classes, hoping that someone more experienced can help me out.

I am processing frames from a video feed, and in each new frame I identify the heads of people below the camera and draw a rectangle around them(this is working fine). These rectangles are then stored in a vector of *RECT* variables.

I have set up a basic class with 2 attributes, an ID number(1,2,3,4...) and a Track History.

So what I want to do with each new rectangle that is being loaded per frame, is check if it overlaps with any of the rectangles from the previous frame (I will do this code similar to Matlabs RectInt function).

And if it does, then I will add it to the History of the class element with some specific ID. If it does not, then I will assign it a new ID and start its own Track History.

What I am struggling to wrap my head around is I am supposed to check the rectangle against all of the previous ones that have been stored? Am I supposed to loop through all the ID numbers and then check with their corresponding History's? Or must I check all of the History's directly?

Note that I am not looking for help with the overlapping function, this is something I will figure out at a later stage, just how to call and use the different class elements.

This section forms apart of a much larger project, so I have spent a few hours setting up what I believe to be the correct layout for this type of class use. This code runs and gives the output which is shown in the image below. I'd really appreciate any pointers, because all tutorials I have found don't quite explain what I want to know.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include "windows.h"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Person
{
public:
    Person(int x);
    ~Person();
    vector<RECT>* processrectangles;
    void Person::InitialiseRectangles(vector<RECT>*);
    void Person::addhistory(RECT);
private:
    int IDnumber;
    vector<RECT> history;
};

Person::Person(int x)
{
    IDnumber = x;
}

Person::~Person()
{
}
void Person::InitialiseRectangles(vector<RECT>* processrectangles) {
    RECT head;
    head.top = 187;
    head.bottom = 218;
    head.left = 183;
    head.right = 209;
    processrectangles->push_back(head);
    head.top = 177;
    head.bottom = 205;
    head.left = 185;
    head.right = 212;
    processrectangles->push_back(head);
    head.top = 156;
    head.bottom = 186;
    head.left = 191;
    head.right = 217;
    processrectangles->push_back(head);
    head.top = 142;
    head.bottom = 172;
    head.left = 193;
    head.right = 221;
    processrectangles->push_back(head);
    head.top = 128;
    head.bottom = 159;
    head.left = 197;
    head.right = 223;
    processrectangles->push_back(head);
}

void Person::addhistory(RECT inpt) { //I dont know how to call this specific to the variables ID number
    history.push_back(inpt);
    //This is simply to limit the history to 15 elements
    if (history.size()>15)
    {
        history.erase(history.begin());
    }
}

int main() {
    int NextID = 1;
    int counter = 1;
    cv::Point pt1, pt2;
    vector<RECT> processrectangles;
    processrectangles.clear();

    //Loads a plain black image
    cv::Mat img;
    const string& image_name = "E:\\James Mallett\\Documents\\Skripsie\\JG Mallett 2016\\HeadData-CBSR\\Black\\black-1.png";
    cout << image_name << endl;
    img=cv::imread(image_name,1);

    Person Start(1); // I know this initialises with an ID of 1

    Start.InitialiseRectangles(&processrectangles);//This was done to simplify my much larger project
    
    for (RECT const& rect : processrectangles)
    {
        // rect is the one Rectangle being processed in this loop, hopefully attaching it to an existing ID
        // or creating its own one
        std::cout << "Rect number: " << counter << std::endl;
        std::cout << "rect.top: " << rect.top << std::endl;
        std::cout << "rect.bottom: " << rect.bottom << std::endl;
        std::cout << "rect.left: " << rect.left << std::endl;
        std::cout << "rect.right: " << rect.right << std::endl;
        pt1.x = rect.left;//Define the points so that drawing is possible
        pt1.y = rect.top;
        pt2.x = rect.right;
        pt2.y = rect.bottom;

        cv::rectangle(img, pt1,pt2, CV_RGB(0, 255, 255), 1);
        cv::imshow("display", img);
        cv::waitKey(1);

        // What I want to try and do, but don't know how:
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Check how many instances of Person there are (This is for interest sake)
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //I want to load the most recent rectangles from the  history of all elements of the Person Class-type, one by one,
        //As they are loaded one-by-one I will check If the rect being processed has an intersecting area with them (Not part of this quesiton)
        //If there is, I will assume they are from the same person and will add it to the history of that specific person, and skip the rest of the loop
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //NOTE: I have already made an add history function that works I assume everything is the same object
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //If it does not match any of them, start a new Person with the NextID and add the rectangle to its history
        // then increment NextID for the next person that is made

        //-----------------------------------

        //Then loop and do the same with the next rectangle

        system("pause");
        counter++;
    }
    cv::destroyAllWindows;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

In the above sequence of rectangles, this would be identified under 1 ID. Once i have been able to get it running correctly with this then I will scale it up so it can work with multiple sequences/people in the same frame

Comment: I don't see anything complicated here. You are going to store a rectangle associated with each frame. Then, you will have to check each rectangle against all the previous rectangles. There's nothing earth-shattering here. Now, this is not going to be very efficient. After a while things will slow down dramatically. But that's what you want to do, and as long as you decide that you have to search all previous rectangles, there's no magic wand to wave to make them disappear. You have to search them.

Comment: I think you may have misinterpreted. I plan on checking the new rectangle for similarities against only the most recent entries to the histories of the various objects(each with their own ID), so if there is 4 objects present then it will only check the most recent of each of them. What i'm uncertain about is A) How to find the latest entries for each ID in use, B) How to correctly create new objects with a new history (class structure related I think) and C) How to show the number of objects that have been made?(i.e. check number of IDs that are in use)

Comment: Again, I do not see anything complicated here. A: you just said that you're only saving the last rectangle for each object, problem solved; B: a vector or a map of all objects, so just add a new entry to the vector or the map; C: see B - both vector and map have size().

Comment: Okay. Again, I am saving each rectangle into the history of each specific object(See code, history length of 15 locations). And then when analysing each new rectangle, searching through all of the IDs and looking at their most recent history (I do not know how to do this search, hence my question). What I was looking for was more of a reassurance that my class and functions have been laid out correctly and a bit of guidance on actually structuring and calling these functions.